# Call for procedure fails but works when run from separate button

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying data from two spreadsheets and condensing the data into one table. Following this procedure, I want to sort the resulting data based on two criteria (Sort Column A ascending and then numerical values in descending order in column E).

When i use  `Call Sort` I get a runtime error 1004 stating that "for this procedure, all cells need to have the same size"

However, when I assign the macro to a separate button and run it from there, it works. Below is the code i use for the sorting feature.

```
Sub Sort()

Range("A8:E100").Sort Key1:=Range("A8"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, Key2:=Range("E8"), Order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Comment: That means you have merged cells in your range. You need to unmerge them: `Range("A8:E100").UnMerge` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If you are using several sheets, make sure to refer to the one you want the range to be taken from. Use `Sheets("nameofyoursheet").Range("A8:E100").Sort ... `Instead of just `Range("A8:E100").Sort ...`   Same for `Range("E8")` in Key2

Comment: @Damian thanks - I tried that and unfortunately (I guess because I didn't close the sheets i was copying from) all cells were unmerged but no sorting was happening.

Comment: @Questionairee I'll write a proper answer, please consider accepting it as the answer to you problem (check the icon) so that others with the same problem can see it as solved and use it too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using several Sheets in Excel VBA, please make sure to refer to each one with the following:
`Sheets("nameofyoursheet").Range("...")` instead of just `Range("...")`
This is necessary because Excel doesn't know which sheet to look in.